# How to add a JSONSchema field with 'type' as 'array', but the values for that will be coming from an async operation (eg. from an API)

Tags: angular, jsonschema

I have tried to go through the doc to find, if anything like this is supported:

"Support for JSONSchema '"type" as "array", when we have a custom format added to it through code, and the field values are recieved through an async service."

Right now, if I have a schema like this:

JSONSchema:

```
  {
      "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
      "type": "object",
      "title": "Incident Filter",
      "definitions": {
      "channelIds": {
      "type": "array",
      "title": "Channel names",
      "description": "Channels which will be monitored for incidents"
     }
      },
       "properties": {
       "channelIds": {
       "$id": "#/properties/channelIds",
       "$ref": "#/definitions/channelIds"
      }
     }
    }
```

The format is getting added through a separate patch file like this:

```
import { JSONSchema7 } from 'json-schema';

import { JsonSchemaPatches } from '@evutils/formly-utils';

export const updateSchemaFields: JsonSchemaPatches = {
channelIds: updateChannelFieldConfig,
};

function updateChannelFieldConfig(json: JSONSchema7): JSONSchema7 {
return {
...json,
format: 'channel-custom-format',
};
}
```

The values for this channel-field is coming from the service, which is later added, when available (async).

It doesn't work and throws random error. How are we supposed to work with a schema field having 'format',whose type is "array", but values are not instantly available?

I have gone through the JSONSchema docs, and didn't find anything related to this type of issue.